# Convert UT in NMock2 to Moq. Also, what does .Will() in NMock2 stand for?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, nmock2

I am new to NMock2 and Moq frameworks. I need some help converting NMock2 code in my current project to Moq code:

```
var myMock= myMockery.NewMock<IMyInterface>();
var myRoleMock = myMockery.NewMock<IRoleInterface>();
var acceptAction = new MyAcceptAction(myRoleMock);
Stub.On(myMock).Method("Accept").Will(acceptAction);
```

I am also not clear what `Will()` in the above code stands for. I do have an idea that `Will(Return.Value(something))` in NMock2 is equivalent to `Returns(something)` in Moq.

So are `Will(something)` and `Will(Return.Value(something))` the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the difference we have to investigate a little. Let's take a look under the hood, `Will` method's signature stands as:

```
public void Will(params IAction[] actions)
```

Now, the `IAction` interface derives from one particulary important interface which is `IInvokable`. As name implies, this allows implementors to be invoked (via `Invoke` method). How does it relate to `Return.Value`?

```
public class Return
{
    public static IAction Value(object result)
    { 
        return new ReturnAction(result);
    }
}
```

Digging a little bit deeper we can find that `ReturnAction` in its `Invoke` method simply sets return value to be used/expected by mock. That's however not the point. `Return.Value` is a simple wrapper creating `IAction` required by `Will`.

Your `MyAcceptAction` also has to implement this interface; to know what exactly happens in the

```
Stub.On(myMock).Method("Accept").Will(acceptAction);
```

line, you will have to check how `MyAcceptAction` is implemented. In particular, the `Invoke` method.

Comment: thnks a lot jimmy.:) .. Just a small doubt ... 
So the usage of the invoke method in the implementation of the IAction or IInvokable interface( in this case, MyAcceptAction class) will be associated only with the Will(something) method? 
If tat is the case, I will b able to use this Interface or invoke method only for NMock2 and not for Moq? ..

Comment: @NiranjanK: Either with `Will` or with NMock itself. `IInovakable` is NMock API, so whatever is happening in `Invoke` method, you'd have to *"translate"* to Moq code.

Comment: Thanks a lot..:) was able to do it with the help of a Callback in Moq.